# how to add expires headers in magento cloud?

Tags: nginx, magento2-cloud

I have problem with expires headers.

I am using magento cloud with nginx server.

Comment: I have updated my answer specific to nginx

Comment: @ShoaibMunir I have tried it but it doesn't worked for me because of magento cloud. if you are give me magento cloud specific solution that will work for me.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: No @ShoaibMunir can not get success on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Cache-Control headers in Nginx by adding the following to your server config’s server location or block.

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)$ {
    expires 365d;
}

location ~*  \.(pdf|css|html|js|swf)$ {
    expires 2d;
}
```